# QGIS with QTCreator windows

Tags: qgis, windows, linux

Is it possible to work on QGIS with QTCreator since most of the build documentation is assuming Linux environment and I have to use windows 7?

all of the old posts in this forum didn't solve this issue it is still not clear how can I integrate Qgis with QTcreator.

Comment: What do you mean work on? Like contribute to the source?

Comment: no, I couldn't find any clear guideline for integrating gqis library with qtcreator in windows environment.

Comment: By looking at that other post and do some searching I found: https://3nids.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/build-and-deploy-c-qgis-app-on-windows/